# python merge list of 1 key and many values dictionaries with the values of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one key and many values for each key

```
d={'POU': ['KO', '0.9.8', '0.99', '0.54']
   'TAN': ['LA', '9', '7.5', '0.0']
   'EST': ['RA', '2', '6.5', '10.01']}
```

and a list of numbers:

```
x = [**1**, **2**, **3**]
```

How can I merge the list with the dictionary to have each list's value appended at the end of each line:

```
d={'POU': ['KO', '0.9.8', '0.99', '0.54', **1**]
   'TAN': ['LA', '9', '7.5', '0.0', **2**]
   'EST': ['RA', '2', '6.5', '10.01', **3**]}
```

In the same order.

Comment: Why do you have stars around your numbers.

Comment: Is your dictionary an `OrderedDict`? If not, unless you are using Python 3.7, you should *not assume* that your dictionary has a specific order. Therefore, you need to either make it an `OrderedDict` or give us some logic to order.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly mentioned by jpp in his comments here, the following solution only works for OrderedDicts or from Python 3.7 on upwards, as otherwise normal dicts do not preserve order:

```
for i, v in enumerate(d):
    d[v].append(x[i])

d
Out[1]: 
{'EST': ['RA', '2', '6.5', '10.01', '**3**'],
 'POU': ['KO', '0.9.8', '0.99', '0.54', '**1**'],
 'TAN': ['LA', '9', '7.5', '0.0', '**2**']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
d={'POU': ['KO', '0.9.8', '0.99', '0.54'],
   'TAN': ['LA', '9', '7.5', '0.0'],
   'EST': ['RA', '2', '6.5', '10.01']}

x = [1,2, 3]

c = 0
for k,v in d.items():
    v.append(x[c])
    c+=1
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'TAN': ['LA', '9', '7.5', '0.0', 1], 'POU': ['KO', '0.9.8', '0.99', '0.54', 2], 'EST': ['RA', '2', '6.5', '10.01', 3]}
```

Comment: This does not match OP's output. Mainly because he hasn't specified whether he needs an `OrderedDict`.